simple python lambda sorting gives different results on different devices
this is my python code for apache hive udf:
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

counter=0
delay={"carrier":0, "nas":0,"weather":0, "security":0, "late_aircraft":0}

for line in sys.stdin:
    counter+=1
    linet = line.strip()
    c,w,n,s,l = linet.split()
    c,w,n,s,l = float(c),float(w),float(n),float(s),float(l)
    delay["carrier"]+=c
    delay["nas"]+=n
    delay["weather"]+=w
    delay["security"]+=s
    delay["late_aircraft"]+=l

for i in delay.keys():
    delay[i]=delay[i]/counter
    # print(delay[i])

print("previous:",delay)
delay=dict(sorted(delay.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True))
print("after",delay)
print("The delay category with the longest average delay is {0}; the average delay time is {1} minutes.".format(list(delay)[0],delay[list(delay)[0]]))

It works before the line print("previous:",delay) But after i sort the dictionary, the output is very strange it is not sorted on any value but indeed changed the order of values (not on keys' alphabetical order, string length, etc):
('previous:', {'weather': 0.0, 'nas': 38.299999999999997, 'security': 0.0, 'carrier': 15.5, 'late_aircraft': 18.399999999999999})
('after', {'late_aircraft': 18.399999999999999, 'nas': 38.299999999999997, 'security': 0.0, 'carrier': 15.5, 'weather': 0.0})

Why isnt 38.299999999999997 the first? I run the same code in local vscode and it works normally. Is this because the old python version that I am using on linux?

You're taking the list returned by sorted and using that iterable to construct a new dictionary named delay. Starting in Python 3.6, dictionaries are insertion-ordered. If you're running this on a version of Python that's older than 3.6, the order will be arbitrary. In general, you should not depend on the order of items in associative collections like dictionaries.

I tried to extract information using tuples and now it works. Thank you for your info!

If you got this solved, please update the post and close it out or answer your own question.
